# Fail to retrieve settings from crashlytics

Tags: android, crashlytics

I'm having some trouble with Crashlytics and Fabric,
Here's my log from logcat

```
I/Fabric(5255): Initializing Crashlytics 2.1.0.21
E/Fabric(5255): Failed to retrieve settings from https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/apps/com.myapp.application/settings
E/Fabric(5255): Error performing auto configuration.
```

I'm lost here, Not sure what i'm supposed to do, the crashlytics docs are very poor and don't help at all. Can someone help me?
I've already setted my project with their IDE plugins.